# Redirect to ?next=/accounts/social/connections/ in django-allauth

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-allauth

I am trying to redirect at `/account/profile` but instead i am getting redirected at `?next=/accounts/social/connections/` while using django-allauth.

Any ideas? My `settings.py` i have set 
 `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'` and on my twitter app the callback url is set to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/twitter/login/callback/`.

I have also tried with creating adapter:

```
from django.conf import settings
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        path = "/accounts/{username}/"
        return path.format(username=request.user.username)
```

and inside `settings.py`:

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'sleep.adapter.MyAccountAdapter'
```

but again its redirected me to:

`localhost:8000/accounts/login/?next=/accounts/social/connections/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things that might be going on here:

1) Social media logins use the class specified by `SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER` (not `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER`) in `settings.py`.  So with your current `settings.py`, when you connect to Twitter it will not call `sleep.adapter.MyAccountAdapter.get_login_redirect_url()`.

2) `/accounts/social/connections/` is the default URL for the view named `socialaccount_connections`.  It is likely that you are trying to **connect** your Twitter account instead of **login** via Twitter.

Make sure the `provider_login_url` tag in your template is **not using** the **process="connect"** argument.

```
{% load socialaccount %}
{% providers_media_js %}
<a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" process="login" method="js_sdk" %}">Login with your Facebook Account</a>
```